# Communication between Javascript clients?

Tags: javascript

I want my website, written in JS, to allow its users to send messages **directly** to one another, without passing through my server. The server can be used initially to get the information required for setting such a connection between users (for example, getting users' IP address, and giving them to other specific users).

Is it possible to do something like this on a website? If so, what do I need in order to send/ receive those messages?

Comment: Not gonna happen. Look into Node.js and Socket.IO and you can happily pass messages between clients...using a necessary server.

Comment: No, not with JavaScript alone. JavaScript runs on the client and you *need* a server to receive and transmit messages between clients.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's possible, but it's a little complex to set up. You would use a RTCPeerConnection which is part of the set of technologies known as WebRTC.

[HTML5Rocks tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#toc-rtcpeerconnection)

Note that although it's generally not too hard to set up a demo using Google stun servers (and your own server for the signaling), doing this at a large scale is harder.

Comment: Don't you need a MCU to enable peer-to-peer communication?

Answer (score 1):

[httprelay.io](http://httprelay.io) requires no additional libraries and with the simple AJAX calls you can send data from browser to browser.